# Array creation in php to be passed in extjs

Tags: php, arrays, json, extjs, ajax-request

Hello every here is a format of my data in array form in extjs

```
data: [
        ['W1',"Avail Qtr Opty",76343,"In-Period Bookings",20031],
        ['W2',"Avail Qtr Opty",178990,"In-Period Bookings",143459],
        ['W3',"Avail Qtr Opty",275758,"In-Period Bookings",208139],
        ['W4',"Avail Qtr Opty",464345,"In-Period Bookings",299032],
        ['W5',"Avail Qtr Opty",580025,"In-Period Bookings",384006],
        ['W6',"Avail Qtr Opty",734469,"In-Period Bookings",406092],
        ['W7',"Avail Qtr Opty",857489,"In-Period Bookings",501320],
        ['W8',"Avail Qtr Opty",969641,"In-Period Bookings",559783],
        ['W9',"Avail Qtr Opty",1076497,"In-Period Bookings",559783],
        ['W10',"Avail Qtr Opty",1173833,"In-Period Bookings",559783],
        ['W11',"Avail Qtr Opty",1279387,"In-Period Bookings",559783],
        ['W12',"Avail Qtr Opty",1412080,"In-Period Bookings",559783],
        ['W13',"Avail Qtr Opty",1736327,"In-Period Bookings",559783]
    ]
```

How can i generate one in this form in php?

Thanks

Comment: Replace `data:` with `$data =`

Comment: i mean how can i generate an array in that form above in php?

Comment: Are you trying to generate the data from a set of data? Or are you just trying to define a variable in PHP?

Comment: @RadicalFanatic i am going to generate data in that form above in php.

Comment: @user2628788 Please let me know if you have any questions about my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

Start by creating an empty array `$data`:

```
$data = [];
```

Then create an array (`$data_element`) to add into the `$data` array:

```
$data_element = ['W1',"Avail Qtr Opty",76343,"In-Period Bookings",20031];
```

Finally, push the `$data_element` array onto the end of the `$data` array via either of the following methods:

```
array_push($data, $data_element);
```

***or***

```
$data[] = $data_element;
```

It is suggested [in the [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) documentation] to use the second option when only adding one element to the `$data` array at a time. If you would like to add multiple arrays to the `$data` at a time, you should use the `array_push()` function. To do this with more rows, you will probably need some sort of for-loop or while loop.